# Can you pass (2) Arguments to the FOR clause of UNPIVOT? - ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I am trying to unpivot a bunch of columns:

[image]

into basically 3 columns (the pivoting part), Service_Area (e.g. 'CSA', 'ESA') and Priority (e.g. 'P1', 'P2') and ActWklyHrs.  I am trying to avoid UNPIVOT'ing twice and having to add a CTE (or worse, a view on a view) and am approaching it by trying to pass two arguements (two new columns) like this:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "STJOF"."vP3factPriorityDistribution" ("ISO_YearWeek", "ISO_Year", "ISO_Week", "Week_Start", "Service_Area", "DistSA_Key_Hash", "Priority", "ActWklyHrs")
AS
(
SELECT
    CONCAT(TO_CHAR(to_date(WEEK_START,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IYYY'), TO_CHAR(to_date(WEEK_START,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW')) AS ISO_YEARWEEK,
    TO_CHAR(to_date(WEEK_START,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IYYY')      AS ISO_YEAR,
    TO_CHAR(to_date(WEEK_START,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW')        AS ISO_WEEK,
    to_date(WEEK_START, 'MM/DD/YYYY')                     AS Week_Start,
    SERVICE_AREA                                          AS Service_Area,
    ORA_HASH(SERVICE_AREA, 99999,1)                       AS DistSA_Key_Hash,
    CASE "Priority"
    WHEN 'P1' THEN 1                                
    WHEN 'P2' THEN 2
    WHEN 'P3' THEN 3 
    END                                                   AS "Priority",
    ActWklyHrs                                            AS ActWklyHrs
  FROM "STJOF"."HistPriorityDistribution" 
  UNPIVOT ( (ActWklyHrs) 
              FOR "Service_Area", "Priority"
              IN ( (CSA_P1) AS 'CSA','P1', (ESA_P1) AS 'ESA','P1', (PCA_P1) AS 'PCA','P1', (DCA_P1) AS 'DCA','P1', (SHA_P1) AS 'SHA','P1' (WSA_P1) AS 'WSA','P1' (WHA_P1) AS 'WHA','P1',
                    (CSA_P2) AS 'CSA','P2', (ESA_P2) AS 'ESA','P2', (PCA_P2) AS 'PCA','P2', (DCA_P2) AS 'DCA','P2', (SHA_P2) AS 'SHA','P2' (WSA_P2) AS 'WSA','P2' (WHA_P2) AS 'WHA','P2',
                     (CSA_P3) AS 'CSA','P3', (ESA_P3) AS 'ESA','P3', (PCA_P3) AS 'PCA','P3', (DCA_P3) AS 'DCA','P3', (SHA_P3) AS 'SHA','P3' (WSA_P3) AS 'WSA','P3' (WHA_P3) AS 'WHA','P3'
                 ) 
          )
);
```

Is it possible without using a CTE and UNPIVOT'ing twice?  Is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply `substr()`?

```
select week_start, substr(str, 1, 3) as service, substr(str, 4) as priority, hrs
  from test 
  unpivot (hrs for str in (CSA_P1, ESA_P1, CSA_P2, ESA_P2, CSA_P3, ESA_P3))
```

You can also do everything in `unpivot` clause:

```
select *
  from test 
  unpivot (hrs for (service, priority) in (CSA_P1 as ('CSA', 'P1'),
                                           ESA_P1 as ('ESA', 'P1'),
                                           CSA_P2 as ('CSA', 'P2'),
                                           ESA_P2 as ('ESA', 'P2'),
                                           CSA_P3 as ('CSA', 'P3'),
                                           ESA_P3 as ('ESA', 'P3') ) )
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=962f556c5676689fdcfcbbe6c9fcae03)</sup>**

Comment: So, I think I was doing exactly what you suggested with your unpivot code, but you indirectly answered my question by providing the correct syntax.  It seems that the problem was a missing set of paranthesis around the (2) arguments to the FOR clause and a corresponding set around their values in the IN clause.

So the answer is, YES, you can pass two arguements to the FOR clause of UNPIVOT.

Answer (score 0):

`````
              FOR ("Service_Area", "Priority") --PARANTHESIS WERE NEEDED HERE
              IN ( (CSA_P1) AS ('CSA','P1'), (ESA_P1) AS ('ESA','P1'), (PCA_P1) AS ('PCA','P1'), (DCA_P1) AS ('DCA','P1'), (SHA_P1) AS ('SHA','P1'), (WSA_P1) AS ('WSA','P1'), (WHA_P1) AS ('WHA','P1') --AND AFTER EACH 'AS',
                    (CSA_P2) AS ('CSA','P2'), (ESA_P2) AS ('ESA','P2'), (PCA_P2) AS ('PCA','P2'), (DCA_P2) AS ('DCA','P2'), (SHA_P2) AS ('SHA','P2'), (WSA_P2) AS ('WSA','P2'), (WHA_P2) AS ('WHA','P2'),
                     (CSA_P3) AS ('CSA','P3'), (ESA_P3) AS ('ESA','P3'), (PCA_P3) AS ('PCA','P3'), (DCA_P3) AS ('DCA','P3'), (SHA_P3) AS ('SHA','P3'), (WSA_P3) AS ('WSA','P3'), (WHA_P3) AS ('WHA','P3')
                 ) 
````          )
`````